# get value from radiobox in fabrik

Tags: radioelement

hello i am using this code in fabrik

```
$radioelement = '{tablename___radioelementname_raw}';

if ($radioelement == 'yes') {
   return 'E';
} else {
   return 'NE';
}
```

to retrieve value from a radioelement

I have 2 issue with it:
I want that if yes=E, if NO= NE, if nochoice is made=Blank, because the radioelement can be blank until i don't make a choice
Also the value don't get update when changingthe radiobox value. It store the correct value, but i want to see th evalue changing when update!
thanksfor  help

p.s.
ok i was able to add thecodeforthe properchoice

```
    $radiohaart = '{lista___haart_raw}';if ($radiohaart == 'SI') {return 'E';}if ($radiohaart == 'NO') {return 'NE';} if ($radiohaart == '') {return '';}
```

and it works
still need the update feature..and i haveno clue for it

Comment: solved with enabling ajax.thanks